# Rules- how can I redirect a user to view their profile only when they update their profile?

Tags: rules, redirection

I want to redirect users to their profile (/user) after they save changes to their profile settings (/user/[uid]/edit).

If their accounts are updated in another manner (by rules, etc.), I do not want them to be redirected.

I made a rule like this:

- Event-> After updating an existing account
- Actions-> Page redirect to user/[account:uid]

This redirects properly; however, on my site sometimes user accounts get updated when a user adds content.  Adding content then also causes this rule to get called, which I don't want.  I only want the user to be redirected if they updated their account details at user/[account:uid]/edit.

I tried adding:

- Condition: Path has URL alias: user/[account:uid]/edit

However, then the redirect ceases to function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ "rules_cw_profile_redirect_user_to_profile_page_after_edit" : {
      "LABEL" : "Redirect user to profile page after editing account",
      "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
      "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
      "ON" : [ "user_update" ],
      "IF" : [
        { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-page:url" ], "value" : [ "account:edit-url" ] } }
      ],
      "DO" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "user" } } ]
}
```